# 97 Jeep Cherokee check gauges light came on and then my battery gauge dropped down to 9 didn't lose any power?

Tags: electrical, battery, jeep, power, cherokee

I'm so confused I had just left my house and got 3 blocks away and my check gauges light came on, then my battery gauge dropped down to 9v. My Jeep didn't lose power, and the radio, heat, lights and everything stayed on. It wasn't even running funny. Then, after being parked for a few hours I drove it again and the battery gauge was back at 14. It wasn't till the next day that it did it again... I'm at a loss and don't know where to start?

Comment: Pull your battery and have it checked. I'll bet you have a bad or dieing cell in it. It is often called a "surface charge" where a cell will have just enough charge to say it's "good" and die when you need it most.

Comment: I just got a new battery a few months ago took the jeep up to napa they tested it n its a bad alternator

Answer (score 4):

Just to post the OP's answer to get this closed out:

"I just got a new battery a few months ago took the jeep up to napa they tested it n its a bad alternator."